# How to pass data between RatingBars in android?

Tags: android, ratingbar

I have ratingBar1 in expandableListView childView in Activity1 and ratingBar2 in Activity2. RatingBar1 is disabled. 
What I would like to do, is when I set rating on ratingBar2, ratingBar1 would change it's rate into the same, but I have no idea how to do that.
Could anyone tell me how to do it?
I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: If both the rating bars are in different activity then what is the issue?

Comment: i could have and idea how to do that if I had ordinary listView. But as I am working with expandable, i set all the child's properties in adapter. So if the data from Activity2 goes to Activity1, I don't know how to pass it from Activity1 into adapters' getChildView, because that is where my ratingBar1 is.

Answer (score 1):

That's so simple, you should get the value of rating bar of activity1 and pass it with the intent.putExtras method to the activity2, there you can use the value to set the rating bar in your activity2 in the onCreate method. Or you can use shared preference for that.